# Why is NA | FALSE = NA?

Tags: r, boolean, logical-operators

I first wondered why 
`FALSE | NA`
returns
`#> [1] NA`, while
`TRUE | NA` returns
`#> [1] TRUE`.

Then I read the explanation that "because the value of the missing element matters in `NA | FALSE`, these are missing".
So I tried 
`TRUE | FALSE`  and
`FALSE | TRUE`. 
And indeed, both return 
`#>[1] TRUE`.
It makes sense that because the result of `NA | FALSE` depends on the value of NA, it returns NA, while the value of NA does not really matter for `NA | TRUE` to be TRUE.
However, can someone explain why `TRUE | FALSE` returns TRUE?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, it asks whether at least one side is `TRUE`. As there is one `TRUE` value, the result is also `TRUE`.

It is the same as with:

```
1 > 0 | 0 > 2
[1] TRUE
```

Conversely, when it asks whether all sides are `TRUE`:

```
TRUE & FALSE
[1] FALSE
```

As with the numerical example:

```
1 > 0 & 0 > 2
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Nice. This also explains the `&` operator and why `TRUE & FALSE` returns `FALSE`...

Comment: Great! Thanks. I still wonder a bit why it is that "at least one side" has to be TRUE to return TRUE. Why not "at least one side" has to be FALSE to return FALSE? .. But I'm satisfied with this answer for now :)

Comment: Maybe it has a serious explanation (like when `TRUE` is converted to a numeric value, then it is represented as `1`, so it has priority over `FALSE` which is represented as `0`), but I think it is mostly convention (even the assignment of `0`/`1` is) :)

Answer (score 1):

For the operation `|`, ***the output is `TRUE` as long as at least one of its condition is `TRUE`***. For instance `TRUE | FALSE| FALSE | FALSE` gives `TRUE`, but `FALSE | FALSE| FALSE | FALSE` gives `FALSE` since it has no `TRUE` condition.

Since `NA` could be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but you don't know what it exactly is.

- In this sense, `FALSE | NA` might be equivalent to `FALSE | TRUE` (which gives `TRUE`) or `FALSE | FALSE` (which gives `FALSE`), which are two possibilities and still not available, so `FALSE | NA` returns `NA`.
- However, for `TRUE | NA`, it is always `TRUE` since it is not depends on `NA` (`NA` as either `TRUE` or `FALSE` does not affects the result)

Comment: From the R documentation: "NA is a valid logical object. Where a component of x or y is NA, the result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous. In other words NA & TRUE evaluates to NA, but NA & FALSE evaluates to FALSE. "

Comment: @otwtm yes, this is as explained in my answer

Comment: yes, just wanted to back up your answer with reference :)